# Convergence of a sequence with greatest integer.

Tags: real-analysis

Is the sequence $\frac{1}{n^2}([\alpha]+[2\alpha]+......+[n\alpha]),\alpha\in R$ convergent? if $\alpha$ is an integer then it's done. How do i solve it for non integer values?
A hint would really help.

Comment: Notation:  The modern convention is to use $\lfloor \alpha \rfloor$ for greatest integer.  That uses the syntax "\lfloor \alpha \rfloor".

Comment: Use that $k\alpha=[k\alpha]+\varepsilon_k$ with $\varepsilon_k\in [0,1[$ (and hence $0\leq \frac{\varepsilon_1+\cdots+\varepsilon_n}{n^2}\leq 1/n$)

Answer (score 1):

The $k$-th term satisfies
$ka-1 < [ka] \le ka$.

The sum of the upper bounds is
$an(n+1)/2$
and the sum of the lower bounds is
$an(n+1)/2-n$.

Dividing by $n^2$,
these are
$a\frac{1+1/n}{2}$
and
$a\frac{1+1/n}{2}-\frac1{n}$
and both of these go to
$\frac{a}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

A typically useful inequality for the floor function (greatest integer function) is:
$a-1< \lfloor a \rfloor \leq a$
and equivalently
$\lfloor a \rfloor \leq a < \lfloor a \rfloor +1$